# About the image of the succ function

Tags: agda

I defined the natural numbers as usually:

```
data Nat : Set where
  zero : Nat
  succ : Nat → Nat
```

and i.e the number one should be

```
one : Nat 
one = succ zero
```

Later on, we can define the image datatype,

```
data Image_∋_ {A B : Set} (f : A → B) : B -> Set where
  im : (x : A) → Image f ∋ (f x)
```

And to prove something like "the one is in the Image of the successor function" I wrote:

```
one-succ : Image succ ∋ one
one-succ  = im zero
```

I would like to have the following.

- Define the predecessor function that not allowed zero as an input just its successors. So the next is not valid.

> ```
> pred : Nat → Nat
> pred zero  = zero
> pred (succ n) = n
> ```

- I would like to have a variable called Z⁺ representing the positive numbers but using in its definition the image of successor function (Image_∋_ data type defined above).

Comment: Do you mean that `pred`'s type should be `∀ {n} → Image succ ∋ n → Nat`?

Comment: yes, something like that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Image f ∋ y` reads as "there is some `x` such that `y ≡ f x`". Pattern matching on `Image f ∋ y` by `im x` reveals the `x`.

So an element of type `Image succ ∋ n` is a proof that `n` is of the form `succ m` where `m` is carried inside that element. Hence the definition is simply

```
ipred : ∀ {n} → Image succ ∋ n → Nat
ipred (im m) = m
```

because `n ≡ succ m` and the predecessor of `succ m` is `m`.

It reads nicer if we rename `im` to `isucc`:

```
open Image_∋_ renaming (im to isucc)

ipred : ∀ {n} → Image succ ∋ n → Nat
ipred (isucc m) = m
```

Another way of writing the same thing is

```
data Image_∋_ {A B : Set} : (A → B) → B → Set where
  _·_ : (f : A → B) → (x : A) → Image f ∋ f x

pred : ∀ {n} → Image succ ∋ n → Nat
pred (.succ · m) = m
```

Here `f` in `Image f ∋ y` is an index rather than a parameter, so `_·_` (previously `im`) now receives two arguments: a function and its argument. It's not possible to pattern match on functions, but `.succ` is an "irrefutable pattern", i.e. it says "`f` can be nothing, but `succ`".

---

`Nat⁺` can be defined as

```
data Nat⁺ : Set where
  nat⁺ : ∀ {n} → Image succ ∋ n → Nat⁺
```

`succ⁺` receives a natural number (implicitly) and a proof that this number is of the form `succ m` for some `m`.

You can always take the predecessor of a positive natural number:

```
pred⁺ : Nat⁺ → Nat
pred⁺ (nat⁺ (im m)) = m
```

But since `Nat⁺` is a non-indexed one-constructor data type, it can be defined as a record:

```
record Nat⁺ : Set where
  constructor nat⁺
  field
    {pred⁺} : Nat
    image   : Image succ ∋ pred⁺
open Nat⁺
```

`open Nat⁺` introduces `pred⁺ : Nat⁺ → Nat` in scope.

Comment: That was exactly I was thinking about. One question more, in nat+ definition, is necessary use of \forall, or just is syntax sugar for writing {n : Nat} ?

Comment: @jonaprieto, it's just a sugar.

Comment: Note that `∀ {n}` isn't syntax sugar for `{n : Nat}` because the type information was omitted, i.e. `∀ {n}` is syntax sugar for `{n : _}`. See the documentation [here](http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/function-types.html#notational-conventions).

Comment: **asr**, I should have clarified that indeed. Thanks. @jonaprieto, please, see what **asr**'s wrote.